# UIDocumentsInteractionController shows iBooks but doesn't open it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidocumentinteraction

My UIDocumentsInteractionController is working as far as  presenting an action sheet with a button that says "iBooks" but when I click on that button, it just dismisses and it doesn't take me to iBooks. Here's my code:

```
NSString *filenamePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp.%@", [[file path] pathExtension]];

    NSString *docDir = [DataCenter getDocumentsDirectoryPath];

    NSString *fullPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filenamePath];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *c = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

    BOOL success = [c presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:buttonBack animated:YES];
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those stuck at this: You don't need to set yourself up as UIDocumentInteractionController's delegate at all.

Problem was `[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url]` is being autoreleased. It  thought it would be retained internally by the action sheet being shown but apparently it's not.
So yea, gotta retain it until action sheet dismisses.

Comment: Wow - okay this really is the case even with ARC!! You need to create a property named `self.interactionController` (or similar) and alloc-init to that, or it gets released. Thanks @PragmaOnce!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` methods `documentInteractionController:willBeginSendingToApplication:` and `documentInteractionController:didEndSendingToApplication:`. If your view controller is the delegate of the document interaction controller, that should clue you in to where the problem may be.

Also, you should validate that the file you're trying to use elsewhere (a PDF I assume) is actually a what you expect it to be.

Comment: The file exists and is a PDF(verified that by downloading the documents folder via Xcode). The delegate methods don't get called...

Comment: Did you add your viewcontroller as the delegate? Just putting in the methods isn't enough. YOu need to do `c.delegate = self`

Comment: yes...Thing is, I don't know what delegate methods to implement. The ones you mentioned are simply return void so doesn't matter if I implement them or not (but i did anyways). The other ones I found in documentation that did ask for BOOL as return were documentInteractionController:controller:canPerformAction: and documentInteractionController:controller:performAction: and I am returning YES from both of them....

Comment: Are those methods being called? If they are being called, then the documentInteractionController is working right. Also, have you double checked that the PDF didn't show up in iBooks already?

Comment: Nevermind, just found out the problem. Don't need a delegate, problem was i wan't retaining UIDocumentInteractionController (i thought it would be retained by some internal entity, most likely the modal sheet being present but it's not). Thanks for your help though :)