# UIDocumentInteractionController not transferring to target application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

My app is generating an image which I'm attempting to pass to Instagram using a document interaction controller and [their hook](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/). Oh, this is using iOS 5.1.

I have the UIDocumentInteraction action sheet showing up properly but the issue is that once the user select "open in Instagram" the sheet is dismissed and nothing happens.

The code:

```
// Method returns a path to the generated image
NSURL *finalCompositePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self generateFinalImage:@"instagram"]];
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://camera"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    //imageToUpload is a file path with .ig file extension
    documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:finalCompositePath];
    documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    documentInteractionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Caption Test" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.ShareButton animated:YES];
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out, turns out that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792228/uidocumentsinteractioncontroller-shows-ibooks-but-doesnt-open-it

Answer (score 3):

[UIDocumentsInteractionController shows iBooks but doesn't open it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792228/uidocumentsinteractioncontroller-shows-ibooks-but-doesnt-open-it) has the correct answer for apps using arc. UIDocumentInteractionController must be a property of the class.

BUT ALSO!!!
If you are supporting down to ios5, make sure the image you've saved is a type ".igo" (not .jpg or .png). 

IOS6 will open it up in instagram, but IOS less than 6 will just dismiss the UIDocumentInteractionController without proceeding to instagram.

Comment: I'm getting this behavior with all extensions to open any app on iOS 6 with the 7.1 SDK